# how to - github two factor authentication with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-plugin

I have to use the two factor authentication feature of github. That is fine. I am unable to comprehend how to use that with Eclipse. 
Whenever I commit my code or perform any activity, the only prompt I get from eclipse is to enter repository, userid and password.
I have egit also installed but that does not help. 
Issue arrives in both Mac and Windows OS
Does anyone out there know how to do this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Although I'm by no means an expert on this, it sounds like you should be using a [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/#through-the-command-line)

Comment: Thanks David. You were right. I generated the Personal Access Token and then I copied the token and pasted it as my password in Eclipse. This worked for me.. thanks a bunch. Maybe you are an expert and do not know it  yet? :)

Comment: With Personal access token: "Error validating settings: Not Found"

Comment: Detailing exactly how to do this in the Eclipse GUI would be extremely helpful

Comment: For Eclipse use this link https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/

Comment: "With Personal access token: "Error validating settings: Not Found" - Had this error too: You just have to remove the ".git" from the server url (https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/846969/)

Comment: Use Directly your generated that `Personal Access Token` as a `password` 100% works, Enjoy

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me in Windows:

1. [Create **Personal Access Token**](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) to authenticate to GitHub. Copy this token for step 3.
2. In Eclipse open Window → Preferences → Team → Git → Configuration → Tab Repository Settings:

   - Select your repository and change the url for remote as follows:
     https://github.com/yourUserName/yourRepository
     (without the ending .git)
3. Push your changes to github as usual. If you are asked to enter your github credentials enter your username and as password your above generated **Personal Access Token**.

Answer (score 10):

1. Login to your Github Profile
2. Go to Setting
3. Go to Developer Setting
4. Click on Generate New Token
5. Give a name to your Token, select all the Check Boxes.
6. Generate the token.
7. Your token will be created, copy the token, and paste it in eclipse in the password section while importing project from Git. Username will be your git Username. Select HTTPS mode while importing in Eclipse.
8. Now you will be able to see your Branch. Pull appropriate one.

Thanks!

Comment: This works for me, but I did it before with Github CLI. Do you know if i should paste the token only in eclipse? Did I need to paste in eclipse login and did gh auth with-token...? Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, this also works with Azure devops personal access tokens

Answer (score 0):

I follow the steps of @TheWoops. however, I initially tried to reuse a previously created Personal Access Token (2mo old). That did not work (same error messages). I then created a new PAT (with repo privileges) and able to get rid of the error when committing in Eclipse.

Comment: I don't want to have to import an entire project from GitHub just to change my password sent to GitHub by Eclipse Git when I do a transaction.  Does anyone know where to go in Eclipse Git to edit the remote credential used for GitHub?

Comment: @pbierre, solution found at [eclipse.org forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1107138/), which I paraphrase here as:
* Go to the Git perspective (from upper right icons in Eclipse)
* In tree at left, open a repository / Remotes / origin, to see the hyperlinks below it
* right-click one of the hyperlink items and choose "Change Credentials..."

Comment: Here's how you use the new token:
User: same account/user name you've been using
PW:  (token string) serves as new secure password

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't want to have to re-enter the PAT everytime you synch there is an option to "Store in Secure storage", check that.
It's found under this menu: "Preferences | General | Security | Secure storage", in Eclispe 4.12.x

it also shows the "Storage location" of this file in the "contents" tab here.

Answer (score -1):

Also, if you are a member of an "Organization" and it requires SAML / OAuth for SSO, you need to take the additional step of "authorizing" the PAT for your org.

see here:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on/authorizing-a-personal-access-token-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on