# Eclipse JUnit 5 support

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit5

Currently, JUnit 5 is just out with a "stable" version.
IntelliJ supports JUnit 5 according to the Website.
My question is if eclipse is supporting JUnit 5 as well, and if not when it is going to be supported.
With supported I mean if I can run JUnit 5 tests without the need for a `@RunWith(PlatformRunner.class)` annotation.

EDIT October 2017: Eclipse now [officially supports JUnit 5](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7.1a/#junit-5-support) as of Eclipse Oxygen1.a (4.7.1a)

Comment: Tried google? Like ... http://www.codeaffine.com/2016/02/18/junit-5-first-look/

Comment: @Jägermeister I read that post already... The thing is when this post got posted when JUnit 5 was still in alpha -> no Support at all... Now IntelliJ supports it.

Comment: You might want to follow [Eclipse Bug 488566](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488566).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow not a product support mailing list.

Comment: What's the point of closing the question once it exists? It is not going to be deleted and it will continue to show up high in google searches.

Comment: @Ghostcat never answer to Google a question, google now point .... here see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run *JUnit 5* tests in *Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen* after installing the *JUnit 5 Support (BETA) for Oxygen 4.7* plugin that you can find in the Eclipse Marketplace. After a complete Eclipse restart, open your project properties at

> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> JUnit -> JUnit 5

Answer (score 7):

With `Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2`, you can run `JUnit 5` tests after annotating the class with `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` as follows:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class Junit5Demo {

    @DisplayName("First Test")
    @Test
    void firstTest() {
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

[image]

`pom.xml` of the project is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>arpit.aggarwal.junit5.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit5-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.vintage.version>4.12.0-M2</junit.vintage.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M2</junit.platform.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                        <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I know that... I already mentioned it in my question. You may have missed the without part

Comment: @RoiEX in your question you mentioned `@RunWith(PlatformRunner.class)` which I corrected to `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`

Answer (score 1):

quick note: make sure you are using the jupiter Test annotation (org.junit.jupiter.api.Test) and not the old junit.test (junit4).  I wasted several hours trying to get my test to run on junit 5 because of this!

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade

I wrestled with this for a while. I want to contribute to a project using junit 5 tests, but I was using an older version of Eclipse Neon.

I have access to a different machine where the junit 5 tests were working. It seems the more updated versions of Eclipse come with junit 5 functioning. I went to:
https://www.eclipse.org/eclipseide/

Installing the newer version and then loading the project from github took care of the issue. I found that on that other computer it was on version 2021-06 but doing it a simple upgrade (with major upgrades enabled) brought it up to 2021-12 which matches the latest as of the time of writing this answer.

I anticipate this helping me not have issues with with managing updates and upgrades in the future.

Since summer 2021 the approach for integrating Eclipse with GitHub has changed. See this post.

[how to - github two factor authentication with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527522/how-to-github-two-factor-authentication-with-eclipse)