# Junit5: Why does using assertArrayEquals() trigger an AssertionFailedError?

Tags: java, arrays, assert, junit5

Doing some JUnit5 tests in Eclipse, I have a routine that returns a `byte[]`. So I'm using `assertArrayEquals` to compare the result. However instead of failing the test on mismatch (red status, increasing `Errors:`), the test fails (blue status, increasing `Failures:`). The exception trace looks like this then:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: array contents differ at index [4], expected: <105> but was: <77>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:48)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:36)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertArrayEquals.failArraysNotEqual(AssertArrayEquals.java:434)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertArrayEquals.assertArrayEquals(AssertArrayEquals.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertArrayEquals.assertArrayEquals(AssertArrayEquals.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertArrayEquals.assertArrayEquals(AssertArrayEquals.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertArrayEquals(Assertions.java:565)
[...]
```

In my specific case the expected result was like "Mississippi", when the actual result was "MissMissppi". So how should I formulate the test correctly?
I'm running the JRE with `-ea` as I'm using assertions.

Example (a changed test scenario, but the same problem):[image]

Comment: If you expect `"Mississippi"` and the method returns `"MissMissppi"`, then the test ist correct. It is the implementation that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Sounds like the assertions aren't supported by your IDE (maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45922012/1777072).  Also, I would expect "blue" for a mismatch, rather than "red".  Red is for errors occurring in your test.

Comment: which IDE is this? "red status" and "blue status" would need some context.

Comment: @turing85: I'm suspecting that `assertArrayEquals` fails if the arrays have different length. I'll test that ASAP.

Comment: You mention that `assertEquals` does not behave like `assertArrayEquals`. I doubt it, yet I recommend to add an example of both in your posting. Besides: Have you checked that your `@Test` annotation uses `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`? If not you uses Junit5-asserts with JUnit4-Tests.

Comment: I tested again: Whenever the arrays do not match (be it a different element or a different size), Eclipse does not increase `Errors:`, but a `Failures:`.

Comment: I would expect a Failure! Please point out why an Error should occur? `assertEquals` does not throw an error if you compare `"Mississippi"` and `"MissMissppi"`.

Comment: OK, it seems I just got confused with nomenclature: It seems that *Failures* are what I expect to be *Errors*, and vice versa. To me a *failure* is the inability to execute (due to exceptions, maybe), while an *error* is - well - an error in the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The test fails as expected.

> array contents differ at index [4]

What is at index [4]?

`"Miss[i]ssippi"`

> Dec: `105` Hex: `0x69` Char: `"i"`

`"Miss[M]issppi"`

> Dec: `77` Hex: `0x4D` Char: `"M"`

#### Why does it fail with an `AssertionFailedError`?

> [`org.junit.jupiter.api.`]`Assertions` is a collection of utility methods that support asserting conditions in tests. [...] Unless otherwise noted, a failed assertion will throw an `AssertionFailedError` or a subclass thereof.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html

Comment: You are right, I was mixing the concepts of *failure* and *error* as used in JUnit.