# SSH and HTTPS Keys don't work for my Eclipse when trying to connect to GitHub

Tags: git, eclipse, github, ssh, https

I'm trying to connect my Eclipse with GitHub by SSH.

In Eclipse, I've generated an RSA key, saved it, and apply.
I also added the SSH to my Github account.

But I still got the following:

[image: Prompt during connecting by SSH]

[image: SSH fail]

Nor would HTTPS work.
I tried it. It failed, suggesting that I should set `http.sslVerify=false`.
I did it, but it didn't help, and I still got this suggestion.

[image: HTTPS fail]

I'm using Eclipse IDE 2021-09, and have updated the Git plugin.

Comment: You shouldn't set `http.sslVerify=false` unless the site is using a self-signed certificate, which GitHub is not.  Doing so destroys all security for the connection.  The question doesn't provide enough information to know what's going wrong, so I'd suggest trying the operation from the command line and including the output as a code block.

Comment: This related post has a more detailed solution. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527522/how-to-github-two-factor-authentication-with-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527522/how-to-github-two-factor-authentication-with-eclipse)

Comment: This other post has a more detailed answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527522/how-to-github-two-factor-authentication-with-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527522/how-to-github-two-factor-authentication-with-eclipse)

Comment: There is a more detailed answer already posted: [Pushing from Eclipse to my GitHub repository via HTTPS stopped working: "git-receive-pack not permitted" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527522/how-to-github-two-factor-authentication-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Try the process [described here](http://lechmigdal.blogspot.com/2012/08/eclipse-egit-authenticity-of-host-cant.html)

> - In Eclipse switch to "`Git Repositories`" perspective
> - Expand your project, add new Remote repository: see "[Eclipse Remotes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Adding_a_Remote_Configuration)" for details
> - Paste the URI that the remote server provides on your project website
> - Now Eclipse will ask you if you trust the RSA key fingerprint and will add it to `known_hosts` file
> - "Dry-Run" (should work), "Save"

But if you switch to an HTTPS GitHub URL, make sure to:

- no set `http.sslVerify=false`
- use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as password
- memorize it, with "Store in Secure storage", under this menu: "`Preferences | General | Security | Secure storage`", in Eclispe 4.x

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! Yet I solved the problem, despite spending about 4 hours. Eventually, it's a dumb issue about validating GitHub's footprints. I need to accept those footprints to create a known_hosts file under Users/admin/.ssh/ so that GitHub knows I've verified its footprints.

Comment: @EricYoung Yes, that is what the process I mention in the answer does: validate GitHub's footprints to create/update `known_hosts`.