# eclipse gitlab 2fa error "authentication not supported"

Tags: eclipse, gitlab, egit

I'm change my gitlab account to 2fa and allready obtain a personal access token and entered it it my local git (via Windows Credential Helper)

**Push & pull works now fine (with personal access token) from CLI (bash).**

But my eclipse push/pull/fetch results error "authentication not supported".
So eclipse seems not recongnize the password change? (I actually thought this would be done by git itself, but it doesn't seem to be the case)
Even when a remove an add to repro in eclipse again it does not work.

If already read [how to - github two factor authentication with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527522/how-to-github-two-factor-authentication-with-eclipse) (and other) and did not find a solution.
Set the Setting "Store crediantials in secure store by default" does not change anything.

Windows10, Eclipse 4.21.0

Any idea how to "reset" the PW for Eclipse (or force to use personal access token stored in git / Windows Credential Helper).

Comment: In Eclipse, the password is stored in the preferences _General > Security > Secure Storage_, tab _Contents_, node _GIT_. What do you mean by _"I actually thought this would be done by git itself"_. EGit is based on JGit and does not delegate to the command line Git. Please link to the GitLab documentation you followed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the reference to jgit has put me on the right track.

jgit has a small bug and sometimes it comes to not requesting the credentials again, but always show errors.
Deleting the credentials in the SecureStore did nothing for me. (the SecureStore was not active for me)

The solution with

```
Repositoy=>origin=>Change Credentials
```

was not successful for me, the menu item is not offered.

But with

```
Repositoy=>origin=>Configure Push=>Change URI
```

gave me the option of resetting the password (and user if necessary). The change was probably not accepted correctly. But with the next push/fetch the correct query for user/password appeared and with user/accesstoken everything worked again fine.

Fortunately, I only had to do this for one repro and it worked for all of them.

Comment: In your question you said that you use **Eclipse 4.21.0** which is a couple of **years and 10 releases behind**. Please make sure that your answer is correct for the current Eclipse and EGit version. Is your issue reproducible in the current version?

Comment: Ok, my autoupdate was broken since 3 years (and did not show any error). Will fix it and test again.